# matTooltip not working on ios

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's matTooltip. Tooltip is not displayed in ios device - i tried with iphone on both safari & chrome browser. 
Example tootip on the official website even doesen't render on iphone.
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: I tried on an iPad, iOS 11.4 and it works if you longpress the element - exactly as stated in the docs.

Comment: Thanks Sirrocco.. yes it works on longpress.  I had missed to include hammerjs in my  ts file.